# Mac Sonoma can connect to NFS via Finder but not access via terminal

Tags: macos, nfs, macos-sonoma

I need to read files from a NFS storage. Via Finder, I can connect to the server by `nfs://<server>/<path>`, and read files via Finder. The mount appears as `/Volumes/<path>`, but from Terminal, then I try to `ls /Volume/<path>`, it errors out as "Operation not permitted". How to make the NFS storage accessible from Terminal?